# beginner PHP: Html in function displaying code?

Tags: php, html

Currently going through this book:

http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/PHP_Cookbook/Forms

The example is as follows:

```
    <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['stage']) && ('process' == $_POST['stage'])) {
            process_form();
        } else {
            print_form();
        }

        function print_form() {
            echo <<<END
                <form action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]" method="post">
                What is your first name?
                <input type="text" name="first_name">
                <input type="hidden" name="stage" value="process">
                <input type="submit" value="Say Hello">
                </form>
        END;
        }

        function process_form() {
            echo 'Hello ' . $_POST['first_name'] . '!';
        } 
     ?>
```

However... when you load the page it, the form and the button is displayed but it's also printing all the code after

So... the loaded page shows the form correctly but then it displays the text:

```
END; }

            function process_form() {
                echo 'Hello ' . $_POST['first_name'] . '!';
            } 
         ?>
```

Comment: the "END" needs to be at the start of the line, not indented - it will not recognize it if it's indented...

Comment: I recommend **not** using the HEREDOC syntax.  There are a few cases where it can be helpful, but usually in those cases you are loading files for content or in templates anyway.  Also, this isn't a very good book.  You've opened yourself up to XSS attacks by outputting arbitrary data in into the context of HTML with no escaping.  **Always** use `htmlspecialchars()`.  (Unless of course you're not outputting HTML...)

Comment: @Brad Yes, you're right, using templates is much preferred. Using POST or GET data directly in your code is bad practise also, is probably what the cookbook mentioned somewhere (all user input is tainted). But at least we've got his problem answered ;)

Comment: @Raphioly-San There is nothing wrong with using `$_POST` or `$_GET` directly in your code... how else would you get user input?  I assume you're referring to code outputting these directly?

Comment: @Brad LOL You're right, I didn't mean it like that - I meant as in the example given above. Be sure to escape it when you're reusing the data... ;)

Comment: I placed the END; at the start of a new line but it's still not working unfortunately... At least I know this for further reference, not sure why it's not working in this case...

Comment: @optional $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]: IF you're going to use it like that, be sure to put it in curly braces and PHP_SELF should be between quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
    $content = <<<EOL
        contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent
EOL; // will end it

    $content = <<<EOL
        contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent
    EOL; // will NOT end it
```

So it needs to be at the start

Answer (score 0):

EOF will close only if its end tag it's on a line without tabs/other characters before it.

```
   <?php 
    if (isset($_POST['stage']) && ('process' == $_POST['stage'])) {
        process_form();
    } else {
        print_form();
    }

    function print_form() {
        echo <<<END
            <form action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]" method="post">
            What is your first name?
            <input type="text" name="first_name">
            <input type="hidden" name="stage" value="process">
            <input type="submit" value="Say Hello">
            </form>
END; // NOTE THIS, NO TABS BEFORE
    }

    function process_form() {
        echo 'Hello ' . $_POST['first_name'] . '!';
    } 
 ?>
```

If I was in you, though, I would have done this:

```
        echo '<form action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]" method="post">
        What is your first name?
        <input type="text" name="first_name">
        <input type="hidden" name="stage" value="process">
        <input type="submit" value="Say Hello">
        </form>';
```

Much more neater and easier to read. What if you need to put all that code in another cycle? You would need indentate every line, and be sure to not put tabs/spaces before the END; line.

What if another dev with an editor that adds automatic indentation edits that code? :-)

Comment: I would've chosen HEREDOC for that...  And if another dev' would have such an IDE, he should check his settings... ;) No self-respecting IDE would do that... It's tough enough a "Cookbook" gives bad examples... It's like the right recipe with the wrong ingredients... ;)